# Delphi: check internet connection in a separated thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, internet-connection

In my form, when the Ontimer event occurs, a new thread is created that checks if internet connection is active.
This is my code:

```
type
TMain = class(TForm)
...
...

TThread_Check = class(TThread)
  private
    TCPClient : TIdTCPClient;
    procedure InternetCheck;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var Main: TMain;
    Internet, THRD_RUNNING: Boolean;
    OGGI: TDate;
...
...

constructor TThread_Check.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  TCPClient := TIdTCPClient.Create (NIL);
  try
    try
      TCPClient.ReadTimeout := 2000;
      TCPClient.ConnectTimeout := 2000;
      TCPClient.Port := 80;
      TCPClient.Host := 'google.com';
      TCPClient.Connect;
      TCPClient.Disconnect;
      INTERNET:= true;
    except
      INTERNET:= False;
    end;
  finally
    TCPClient.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TThread_Check.Execute;
begin
  Synchronize(InternetCheck);
end;

destructor TThread_Check.Destroy;
begin
  THRD_RUNNING:=false;
end;

procedure TThread_Check.InternetCheck;
begin
  if INTERNET then
    begin
      main.idt.Active:=true;
      OGGI:=main.idt.DateTime;     // Pick internet Date ad assign to OGGI
      main.idt.Active:=false;
    end;
end;

procedure TMain.OnTimerEvent(Sender: TObject);
Var THD : TThread_Check;
begin
  if (THRD_RUNNING = False) then
    begin
      THRD_RUNNING := True;
      thd := TThread_Check.Create;
      thd.FreeOnTerminate := true;
      thd.Priority := tpNormal;
      Thd.Resume;
   end;
end;

procedure TMain.OnCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  THRD_RUNNING:=false;
end;
```

Initially it seems to work; my application starts and if internet go down, it notices (in the main form, if INTERNET=false something happens...).

The problem is that after some time the application is active, it freezes and in Windows Task Manager, the Analyze Wait Chain shows me another Thread pending, and this time if internet go down my application does not react!

What's the problem??
Please, help me!
Thanks!
Emanuele

Comment: There are a few problems here: (1) `TThread.Create` runs in the main thread. It seems like you are not aware of this. (2) `TThread.Execute` is the code that is run in the new thread. But in your case, it only contains a GUI update routine (or what is `idt`?), which is very odd because you must only update the GUI in the main thread. The `Synchronize` helps here, but effectively makes your code single-threaded. (3) The thread's destructor lacks the `inherited` part, which is probably very important.

Comment: Thank you Andreas for your response.
Yes, I'm not aware about multithreading in delphi, that's why I hope someone could help me.
Could you modify my code correctly, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TThread` constructor runs in the thread that calls it, which in your case is the main UI thread. The only thing you are running in your worker thread is `Synchronize()`, which runs its code in the main UI thread, defeating the purpose of using a worker thread at all.

You need to move your TCP connect/disconnect logic from the constructor into `Execute` instead. Use `Synchronize()` only to update the UI. In which case, you could just use the `OnTerminate` event instead, which is already synchronized for you.

For example:

```pascal
type
  TMain = class(TForm)
    ...
  end;

  TThread_Check = class(TThread)
  private
    TCPClient : TIdTCPClient;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

var
  Main: TMain;
  Internet, THRD_RUNNING: Boolean;
  OGGI: TDate;

...

constructor TThread_Check.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  TCPClient := TIdTCPClient.Create (NIL);
  TCPClient.ReadTimeout := 2000;
  TCPClient.ConnectTimeout := 2000;
  TCPClient.Port := 80;
  TCPClient.Host := 'google.com';
end;

procedure TThread_Check.Execute;
begin
  try
    TCPClient.Connect;
    TCPClient.Disconnect;
    INTERNET := True;
  except
    INTERNET := False;
  end;
end;

destructor TThread_Check.Destroy;
begin
  TCPClient.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMain.OnInternetCheckDone(Sender: TObject);
begin
  THRD_RUNNING := False;
  if INTERNET then
  begin
    Main.idt.Active := true;
    OGGI := Main.idt.DateTime;
    Main.idt.Active := false;
  end;
end;

procedure TMain.OnTimerEvent(Sender: TObject);
var
  THD : TThread_Check;
begin
  if (not THRD_RUNNING) then
  begin
    thd := TThread_Check.Create;
    thd.FreeOnTerminate := True;
    thd.OnTerminate := OnInternetCheckDone;
    Thd.Resume;
    THRD_RUNNING := True;
  end;
end;

procedure TMain.OnCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  THRD_RUNNING := False;
end;
```

Comment: Yesss!! It's working now!
Thank you Remy, now I understand where I was wrong!

Comment: Is OnInternetCheckDone run in MainThread?

Comment: @GBg Yes, it is run in the main UI thread, as `TThread.OnTerminate` is a `Synchronize()`'d event, as I stated in my answer.

Comment: I used a log to the main thread 
          if  TThread.CurrentThread.ThreadID <> MainThreadID then
            Log.d('Run in Other Thread')
          else
            Log.d('Run in Main Thread');
Viewport3D1.UsingDesignCamera := False;
But sometimes it hangs in the execution of this command : Viewport3D1.UsingDesignCamera := False;

I used Synchronize to be more sure, so far I had no problem.